# How would I encrypt a file with a User's Active Directory credentials?

Tags: c#, selenium, file, asp.net-core, encryption

I am generating a PDF file using Selenium on the backend of my web application (ASP.NET Core 3.1). The PDF file contains customer data and it can be opened by anyone who has access to the filesystem on the server.

However I want to take extra precautions and protect my customer data my encrypting the PDF file that has been generated.

Can anyone please give me any idea what I can do to protect this file?

Comment: As you have tagged your question asp.net-core I assume those generated PDF files are requested by your customers using an asp.net web page? Do you plan to decrypt the PDF files in this asp.net application or do the client get an encrypted file and have somehow decrypt it?

Comment: The client currently downloads the file using the browser and uses Adobe PDF (brower plugin or the Desktop software) to view it. I am using JSRuntime to download the file in the client to the users download folder

Comment: You still have not answered my question: where should the PDF file be decrypted? If it planned to do so before download the question is if the download data is provided by your asp.net app.

Comment: @Robert, I am not really sure. What would provide the best experience to my users?

Comment: Of course if the users don't get in touch with the decryption and if the decryption takes place at the latest possible time - thus right while the user downloads the file via HTTPS. Problem is just how to store the used keys, saving them somewhere on the same server would defeat the purpose to protect them against "anyone who has access to the filesystem on the server".

Comment: I am using JWT tokens for the sessions. AD Login for user name/password.